# Printing an Array as a String with 10 elements per line

Tags: java, arrays

```
// Line in Main Code 
public class Assignment7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;
    char userChoice;
    int newVal, index;
    IntegerList intList = null;

    printMenu();

    do {
        System.out.print("Please enter a command or type? ");
        input = scan.nextLine();
        if (input.length() != 0)
            userChoice = input.charAt(0);
        else
            userChoice = ' ';
        switch (userChoice) {
        case 'a':
            System.out.print("How big should the list be? ");
            intList = new IntegerList(scan.nextInt());
            scan.nextLine();
            System.out.print("What is range of the values for each random draw? ");
            intList.randomize(scan.nextInt());
            scan.nextLine();
            break;
        case 'b':
            System.out.println(intList.toStrng());
            break;
```

The above code is part of my main code, where I get user input and as them to set the boundary conditions of the array. case 'b' asks to print out the array by calling the function in the class which should return the array as a string with 10 elements per line.

```
// line in class
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class IntegerList {

private int arrSize;

public  IntegerList(int size) {
    size = arrSize;
}   

private int[] IntArray = new int[arrSize];

public void randomize (int num) {
    for(int i = 0;i<IntArray.length;i++) {
        IntArray[i] =(int) (Math.random()*(num+1));
    }

}   


public void addElement(int newVal, int index) {
    for(int i = index;i<IntArray.length;i++) {
        int temp = IntArray[i];
        IntArray[i]=newVal;
        IntArray[i+1]=temp;
        if(i == IntArray.length){
            increaseSize(IntArray);
        }
    }

}

private static void increaseSize(int[] x) {
    int[] temp = new int[2*x.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<x.length;i++) {
        temp[i]=x[i];
    }
    x = temp;
}

public void removeFirst(int nextInt) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public String range() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public String toStrng() {
    String arrayOut = " ";
    for(int i = 0; i<IntArray.length; i++ ) {
    if(i%10 == 0 ) {
        arrayOut+="\n";
    }

    arrayOut += IntArray[i] + " " ;
    }

    return arrayOut;
}

}
```

I'm trying to convert the array into a string and then return int and have it display 10 elements per line. I'm pretty sure I have the logic right, however, when I run the code, it does not display the array at all. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: What in your code do you think *should* produce the display you want?

Comment: Hint: you'll need a print statement to print.

Comment: Still doesn't change anything. I forgot to add the println line in the question, but its the code and there still is no output

Answer (score 0):

Look at how you are creating your array of integers through your current constructor...

```
public  IntegerList(int size) {
    size = arrSize;
}   

private int[] IntArray = new int[arrSize];
```

When you call

```
intList = new IntegerList(scan.nextInt());
```

in your menu program, your array list won't magically know it needs to be re-initialized. It will be 0 since the value of arrSize is always 0 when you create your IntegerList object. Furthermore you have the assignment of the variables switched. Change your constructor to the following

```
private int[] IntArray = null;

public  IntegerList(int size) {
    arrSize = size;
    IntArray = new int[arrSize];
}
```

Everything seems to work because the size of your array was always 0 and your methods just return.

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize your **arrSize**
You can modify your constructor to initialize **arrSize**

    public  IntegerList(int size) {
    arrSize = size;
    }

Also, in you **toStrng** method, you can just make use of **arrSize** instead of **IntArray.length**